# CarrierWave: Uploads and saves original file...I don't want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, amazon-s3, carrierwave, sidekiq

I am using [carrierwave_backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) to upload images to S3 in a background process with Sidekiq.

Here's my **background_uploader.rb** class...

```
class BackgroundUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/backgrounds/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    "/assets/default.jpg"
  end

  process :resize_to_fit => [1024, 1024]
  process :convert => 'jpg'
  process :fix_exif_rotation

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

  def filename
    @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(current_path.to_s))
    "#{@name}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename
  end

  # Rotates the image based on the EXIF Orientation & applies gaussian blur
  def fix_exif_rotation
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.auto_orient!
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img = img.gaussian_blur(0.0, 20.0)
      img
    end
  end

end
```

**carrierwave_backgrounder.rb**:

```
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :sidekiq, queue: :carrierwave
end
```

**background.rb** contains:

```
mount_uploader :image, BackgroundUploader
process_in_background :image
```

I then run `sidekiq -q carrierwave` to fire up the background workers. All is working good! Upload a file, I see the queue accept it and start working...

If I immediately open up my AWS S3 Console I see the original file in there. Non-resized and un-blurred. Once the job is complete...I refresh S3 and there's the resized/blurred version. Now both images are in there, but I only want the blurred image to be there. In my view I use...

```
 <%= image_tag(@background.image.to_s) %>
```

It displays the original file. If I check the checkbox to remove the file, it does so as it should (deletes the original from S3), but the blurred version stays there.

What's getting uploaded to S3...

- original.jpg (immediate...I don't want this uploaded at all)
- modified.jpg (after job completes)

Long story short: I don't want the original file to upload to S3.

Comment: Does this happen with files with extension ".jpg"?

Comment: Happens with .jpg, .png, etc...I've tried referencing the [wiki article here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Cleanup-original-file-that-wasn%27t-uploaded-like-as-Tempfile) as well and no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the `filename` method, which carrierwave may rely on to find (and delete) the original file. Does the problem go away when you use a filename that doesn't change between when it's initially stored and when you process it?

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Thanks for your help Taavo. It was losing reference to the files (as you mentioned) because of the changing file names. All fixed and I got the background job processing working as well!